# I'm trying to make a program that can run different functions depending on the user's choice in C

Tags: c

I have made three different functions. I'm trying atm to make the user choose which function to operate. For that, I'm trying to use a switch statement. The user inputs two numbers and chooses which function to operate on the numbers. Here's my code currently and it's not working.
MultbyTwo, isFirstBigger, and addVat are the functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multbyTwo (int a){
    return a*2;
}

int isFirstBigger (int a, int b){
    if (a<b){
    printf("1");
    }
    else {
    printf("0");
    }
}

float addVat(float a, float 20){
    return (a/100)*20;
}

int main(){


    int a,b;
    int choice;
    printf("Which Function [0:multbyTwo,1:isFirstBigger,2:addVat]:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    printf("a:\n");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("b:\n");
    scanf("%f",&b);

    switch (choice){
        case 0: printf(multbyTwo(a));
            break;
        case 1: printf(isFirstBigger(a,b));
            break;
        case 2: printf(addVat(a));
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your declaration `float addVat(float a, float 20){` is wrong (you can't have a literal value as an argument). You just need this: `float addVat(float a){`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the program still won't compile

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue I mentioned in the comment, your are also missing format strings from many of your `printf` calls.  Here is a working version of your code, with "///" comments added wherever I've changed something:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int multbyTwo(int a) {
    return a * 2;
}

int isFirstBigger(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) {
    //  printf("%s", "1"); /// You print the result in main!
        return 1; /// You MUST return a value!
    }
    else {
    //  printf("%s", "0"); /// You print the result in main!
        return 0; /// You MUST return a value!
    }
}

float addVat(float a, float vat) { /// Change here to allow a value of vat to be passed
    return (a / 100) * vat;        /// ... and here to use the passed value (not fixed)
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int choice;
    printf("Which Function [0:multbyTwo,1:isFirstBigger,2:addVat]:");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    printf("a:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a); /// Use %d for integers - %f is for float types
    printf("b:\n");
    scanf("%d", &b); /// Use %d for integers - %f is for float types

    switch (choice) { /// each call to printf MUST have the format string as the first argument...
        case 0: printf("%d", multbyTwo(a));///
            break;
        case 1: printf("%d", isFirstBigger(a, b));///
            break;
        case 2: printf("%f", addVat((float)a, 20));/// Now, we must pass the value of "vat" to use in "addVat()"
            break;
    }
    return 0; /// It's good practice to always have this explicit "return 0" in main!
}
```

I hope this helps you! (But I have to say, there is still much room for improvement.)

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.